# Courant and Fritz, Constructing the real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

In chapter 1, page 10, real numbers are found by confining them to an interval that shrinks to "zero" length (we consider subintervals that approximate better and better the position of $x$). Basically, if $x$ is between $c$ and $c+1$, then we can divide that interval into ten subintervals, and we can, then, have $c+\frac{1}{10}c_1\leq x\leq c+\frac{1}{10}c_1+\frac{1}{10}$, where $c_1$ is a digit from zero to nine.

Repeating this process, and making $n\to\infty$ subdivisions, we'll eventually get $x=c+0.c_1c_2c_3...$

I am confused by this, though:
[image: Passage from the book.]

1. How is he constructing that $I_{n+1}$ interval? I get it intuitively, but I don't see the math.
   --**EDIT:**
   If I suppose $c_0-1\leq x$, then I can do $c_0-1+\frac{1}{10}c_1+...+\frac{1}{10^n}c_n\leq x$, and if I say that $n\to\infty$, then I can also write $\underbrace{(c_0-1+\frac{1}{10}c_1+...+\frac{1}{10^n}c_n)}_x-\frac{1}{10^{n+1}}\leq x$, so that $\frac{1}{10^{n+1}})$ is like an infinitesimal.
   Would this be correct for $\left[x-\frac{1}{10^{n+1}},x\right]$? It should be the same with $x\leq c_0+1$ by subtracting $\frac{c_i}{10^i}$s and adding $\frac{1}{10^{n+1}}$.
2. How is he getting the second representation with $c_n-1$? (typo?)
   I see that, maybe, we'd do $c_0\leq x$, and get it to $c_0+\frac{1}{10}c_1+...+\frac{1}{10^n}c_n\leq x$, but we would have $c_{i>0}=9$.
3. Why is there an ambiguity for rational numbers with a power of ten denominator. These can be basically found with the formula I mentioned in the first paragraph. $(p\in\mathbb{N})/10^n$ has always a finite decimal expansion.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Let us begin with $3.$ Not every rational number has a finite decimal expansion, like $\frac{1}{3}=0.\bar 3$. Only the period $\bar 9$ gives an ambiguity like the famous $0.\bar 9=1$. Apart from this, the decimal expansion of a real number is always unique.

Comment: @Peter sure, thanks for the remark. I should've wrote that rationals of the form $(p\in\mathbb{N})/10^n$ are always finite.

Comment: A rational with a power-of-ten denominator has two representations, a finite one and an infinite one. E.g., $37/100$ is $0.37$ but it's also $0.369999999999999999\dots$.

Comment: Right. I could find the decimal expansion of $37$ by having $c_0=x-1$ to get $36.\bar9$, and then divide by $100$. Thanks, @GerryMyerson.